# How to check if Element is a ContainerElement?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Scripting to iterate over a bunch of elements in a Google Doc. I start with a single `Element` and I want to recurse over all its children with code similar to the following:

```
var elements = [rootElement];
while (elements.length > 0) {
  var element = elements.pop();
  // TODO: process element
  if (isContainerElement(element)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.getNumChildren(); i++) {
      elements.push(element.getChild(i));
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to implement `isContainerElement`, though.

If I try the following:

```
function isContainerElement(element) {
  return element instanceof DocumentApp.ContainerElement
}
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot use instanceof on a non-object.

How can I find out if an `Element` is a `ContainerElement`?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better and more robust ways to do this, but this works:

```
function isContainerElement(element) {
  return element.getNumChildren !== undefined;
}
```